# Geo coding with city names google maps

Tags: php, google-geocoding-api

I have developed following code,

```
$geocode=file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".$search_text."&sensor=false");

$output= json_decode($geocode);

$lat = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
 $lng = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
}
```

If I assign Los Angeles to $search_text this is not working. Error "geometry is not defined". How can I get lat lng values of Los Angeles or state like California ?

Comment: What is the value of $output->status?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `urlencode($search_text)` instead of `$search_text` in `$geocode` variable.